# Flexbox & bootstrap on mobile - trouble with align items: center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Here is bootply: https://www.bootply.com/kmfYqoCCLf
there will be black border-top 1px solid in two rows, the problem is that the divs are not same height so they don't create a "one line". how I can make the divs with the border to be same height and centered to the middle same time?
I tried flexbox, but something went probably wrong. It works only if:

```
.line {
  align-items: inherit;
}
```

but in this case, the content of divs is not in the middle.

Thanks for helping me out
Karolina

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, found it myself:

```
.line {
    align-items: inherit;
}

.line > div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```